# Fixed points of self maps

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, polynomials, fixed-point-theorems

Given $m$ points on $S^n$, is there an explicit polynomial self $1-1$ map of minimum degree $f:S^n\rightarrow S^n$ that fixes only these $m$ points? Can we say something about symmetry group of $f$ if $m$ points chosen have some symmetry?

If there is no polynomial map, would there be another explicit self map?

If we relax $1-1$, is something nice possible under condition $f(S_n)\subseteq S_n$?

I am over reals.

Comment: Do you want assumptions on the underlying field? Are you working over $\mathbb C$?

Comment: Oh sorry application over reals.

Comment: As you've stated the problem, the identity map fits, doesn't it?

Comment: I already noticed it. but I thought it is clear I want only $m$ points fixed (added only to sentence there).

Comment: The condition in the last question is redundant.